# How do integrals relate to converging and diverging series?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

When $n$ is an integer greater than $1$,

$\int_0^1{\frac{1}{x^n}}dx$

The answer key says the answer is $\infty$.

Now I have experience with integration, finding convergence/divergence of series, etc. But, I'm not seeing the connection with series. $\frac{1}{x^n}$ is clearly the form of the power series, but how do I connect it with this integral?

This leads to a more general question about the relationship between integrals and series, which I have searched for. I found some decent answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317551/calculus-improper-integrals-vs-series), but I am certainly open to any thoughts about that topic.

Anyways, let me know what you think about solving that integral at the top.

Comment: Do you know the power rule for integrals?

Comment: @EricTowers yes, and when I did that I got $\frac{x^{-n+1}}{-n+1}$ from 1 to 0

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^1{\frac{1}{x^n}}dx$ is an improper integral, because for $x \to 0$ we have $\frac{1}{x^n} \to \infty$.

So, by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral), the value of the integral for $n>1$ is given by:

$$
\int_0^1{\frac{1}{x^n}}dx= 
$$
$$
=
\frac{1}{1-n}(1)^{1-n}-\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{1-n}x^{1-n}=\frac{1}{n-1}\left[\lim_{x \to 0}\;(x^{1-n})-1 \right]
$$ 
that, with the substitution $y=1/x$ becomes:
$$
=\frac{1}{n-1}\left[\lim_{y \to \infty}\;(y^{n-1})-1 \right]
$$
Note that here we have a limit that is the limit of a sequence, not the sum of a series, and, for $n>1$, this sequence is clearly divergent.

---

The last step comes from:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}(x^{1-n})
$$
$$
=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^{n-1}}
$$
$$
=\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{n-1}=
$$
 and the substitution:
$$
\frac{1}{x}=y 
$$
for which we have that if $ x\to 0$ than $y \to \infty$.

Comment: So I see how in the first step you simply integrated and plugged in the limits. I see you set the second term, as a limit, and that's fair enough. However, I don't see how you were able to get rid of the first term as you went to the next step. Also why does the denominator turn from *1-n*  to  *n-1*?

Comment: I added to my answer. I hope it's useful :)

Comment: sorry, I'm still having trouble getting this. So I see that you integrated and put it into two terms: $\frac{1}{1-n}(1)^{1-n}-\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{1-n}x^{1-n}$. I'm guessing the reason the denominator of $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{1-n}x^{1-n}$ becomes *n-1* is because of the negative in front of the limit, making things negative. But then how did you get the *-1* in $\frac{1}{n-1}\left[\lim_{x \to 0}\;(x^{1-n})-1 \right]$. The term $\frac{1}{1-n}(1)^{1-n}$ doesn't simplify to *-1*.

Comment: Note: $-\frac{1}{1-n}=\frac{1}{n-1}$ and $\frac{1}{n-1}$ is a common factor.

Comment: So what happens to the exponent of *1-n* ? Doesn't that make the sign change? How can we factor out $\frac{1}{n-1}$ if *1* is alternating?

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-n}(1)^{1-n}-\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{1-n}x^{1-n}= -\frac{1}{1-n}\lim_{x\to 0}x^{1-n}+\frac{1}{1-n}=\frac{1}{n-1}\lim_{x\to 0}x^{1-n}-\frac{1}{n-1}=\frac{1}{n-1}\left[\lim_{x\to 0}x^{1-n}-1   \right] $

Comment: things are making much more sense, thanks! One last question: in your post you said "this sequence is clearly divergent". Sequences can't be divergent, can they?

Comment: see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence

Answer (score 0):

let $y = x^{-1}$

$dy  = -x^{-2} \ dx\\
dx = - y^{-2} dy$

$\int_{0}^1 x^{-n} \ dx = \int_1^{\infty} y^{n-2} \ dx $

If $n \ge 2$ then the integral is clearly divergent as
$\lim_\limits {y\to \infty} y^{n-2}\ne 0$

If $n < 2$ then $y^{n-2}$ is montonic and decreasing.

$\sum_\limits {k=1}^{\infty} (k^{n-2}) \le\int_1^{\infty} y^{n-2} \ dy\le \sum_\limits {k=2}^{\infty} (k^{n-2})$

if $n\ge1$

$\sum_\limits {k=1}^{\infty} (k^{n-2})$ diverges

if $n < 1$

$\sum_\limits {k=2}^{\infty} (k^{n-2})$ converges

Comment: I don't see how you were able to do this step: $\int_{0}^1 x^{-n} \ $dx = $\int_1^{\infty} y^{n-2} \ dx$

Comment: The limits of integration, $\lim_\limits {x\to 0^+} y(x) = \infty, y(1) = 1.$  Plugging all of these we get $\int_{\infty}^1 (y^n)(-y^{-2}) \ dy.  $ We can flip the limits of integration if we also flip the sign.